# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local'

Tags: npm

Everytime i try to run a npm command i get a wierd error. This happened after i ran  ***npm config set prefix /usr/local*** whilst trying to install react and after that i wasnt able to run a single npm command without this error. If anyone has any idea of what this means or how to fix it  please help ! thanks !

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:211:17)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:83:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:215:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:253:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13
    at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:178:20)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:47:53
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:211
  if (npm.config.get('json')) {
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are getting an EPERM you may need to open up a command prompt and specify 'run as administrator', ' I'm admin on my PC and still need to do this from time to time with NPM scripts

Comment: I do not have admin rights on my work machine. Is there any other way to fix this ?

Answer (score 4):

1. Run `cmd` as administrator
2. `npm config set prefix/usr/local`
   (changed the prefix)
3. `npm start` in normal console

Comment: Thats helps for me

Answer (score 1):

Try installing it globally first, using the command

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

And then, you can create your app using the command,

```
npx create-react-app <Name of your app>
```

Credits : https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9091